# AJAX POST request fails, but data is sent

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I have a AJAX post request that as to send some JSON to a service, but I can't get it to fully work.
The data arrives the service and is saved but my function works as if there was no success and returns me all my error messages.

Can someone explain me why does this happens?
I have searched and I can't find anything that explains why.

```
saveDate: function ($target) {
        var values = $target.data("DateRangesWidget").options.values;
        var beginDate = values.dr1from.split("/");
        var endDate = values.dr1to.split("/");
        var compareBeginDate = values.dr2from.split("/");
        var compareEndDate = values.dr2to.split("/");
        var date = {
            "ID": 1,
            "BeginDate": (beginDate[2] + '-' + beginDate[1] + '-' + beginDate[0]),
            "EndDate": (endDate[2] + '-' + endDate[1] + '-' + endDate[0]),
            "Aggregation": values.aggregation,
            "Comparative": values.comparisonEnabled,
            "ComparationType": values.comparisonPreset,
            "ComparativeBeginDate": (compareBeginDate[2] + '-' + compareBeginDate[1] + '-' + compareBeginDate[0]),
            "ComparativeEndDate": (compareEndDate[2] + '-' + compareEndDate[1] + '-' + compareEndDate[0])
        }
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:9000/json/1',
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(date),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) { //não funciona pq??
                //console.log('added');
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(textStatus);
                //location.reload();
            }
        });
    },
```

Comment: Whats the javascript look like? Post the code in question please.

Comment: We cannot explain what might be wrong without code examples and specific information on how the behavior of your code differs from what you expect.

Comment: can you put the results ? like the ones you get from Firebug ? the more data the easier we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always get the result by register the event of jqXHR object, like done/fail/always/then events, the $.post method will return an jqXHR object.

detail documentation see:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

So if you are testing the response detail you can use code as below:

```
$.post(url, data).always(function(data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown) {

    // do something here.

});
```